# Getting repository will not be vaild error when running sudo apt update

Tags: apt, sudo

Just install Ubuntu 18.04, when I run the command `sudo apt update`, it shows the below error:

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Hit:3 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Get:4 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Get:5 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Reading package lists... Done      
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 7h 31min 57s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 7h 32min 53s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 7h 34min 12s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

Does any one know what causes this problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: Check your system clock (and/or timezone).  Your machine's date/time is set in the future ~7.5 hrs... You haven't worked out time travel have you? - wanna pass me some secrets?

Comment: Well, got resolved by manually setting the timezone. thanks folks